# Using the padding property in combobox components

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox

I made a quick search in Google and I couldnt find what I need, basically, I want to set a padding in my combobox component, so the entire combobox (not the items inside) is a little separated from the previous component.

The combobox is contained inside a VBox container, and above there is a label.

If I use the padding property, what it does is to decrease the Y position of the text inside, but the component doesn't move at all.

Do anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the verticalGap property on the VBox. Or place your Combobox in a Canvas and then give it a y position.

Answer (score 0):

The padding property refers to the inner padding of the component. So if you increase the left margin, the text will move to the right.

You're looking for the margin property, which does what you need.

Comment: There is no margin property in the combobox component, a way I found out to do this, is to put the combobox inside a Box, that way I can use the padding.. but it doesnt seem like a very cool option IMO.

Comment: no I didnt try, I guess I can assign a stylename property and do it that way but.. it still seems a little akward tbh.